# Why doesn't putting a random http link in code cause a compilation error?

Tags: java

For example:

```
public class MyLink{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        http://google.com

        System.out.println("And this works!");
    }
}
```

This code will compile without any problems. Why?

Comment: I can't really explain but I find this question funnier than it actually is.

Comment: same is true for other PL(c/c++) too!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java `http:` is a [label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) which you can use in loops or any pther statements, whereas `//google.com` is a [single-line comment](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/singleline.html).

Answer (score 12):

Java interprets `http:` as a [label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7), and the rest of the line is a comment.

Comment: It's important to note what that label is labeling. If you removed the print statement, the code would not compile.